# Finding Multiple Values in Google Spread-Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a list of roughly 800 VIN numbers that are each in a separate cell. I can and have already created a partial list of these so that they are separated by a comma thinking the find function would be able to highlight multiple cells if comma delineated, but this did not work. Instead of going one by one and using copy/paste plus find to locate each VIN in the second spreadsheet (which is understandably quite tedious and time consuming) I have been trying to find a way so that I can find multiple cells at once. Ex: 123456789, 234567891, 345678912, etc. so that each cell that contains those values will be located. I have tried the power tools improved search function by Adlebits, but it does not have this capability, which leads me to believe the only possible way to achieve this would be through the script editor, if at all. Any recommendations?

Comment: Probably query or filter with arrayformula. Both would likely do the job but it is impossible to recommend one over the other given the sparse nature of your question. In Excel this would be a filter or advanced filter operation.

Comment: Please provide a sample input and desired output.

Comment: Maybe this would help to explain what my question is? https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xSdN42zpL-9SjGtCzvAArfeaccOXaJkGoAOGLYlcDJ4/pubhtml

Answer (score 0):

Try breaking the comma separated list into separate cells and then use conditional formatting to highlight the values. Have a look at my example.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1YBsUz96yN7rxYFjnYI94lAGPMOUS2ScHD2SW417VEeY/copy?usp=sharing

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks so much for your help. I was wondering why your document had nothing in under conditional formatting>

Comment: Apologies.  I copied my example to a new sheet and it must have removed the conditional formatting.  I've added it back in.  Formula: `=OR(A4=$A$2,A4=$B$2,A4=$C$2,A4=$D$2)` on a range `A4:F100` the range can extend as far as it needs to.  The main part of this solution is splitting the comma separated input so that it can be used more easily.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of 800 vins and you want to search that list for a list of vins and create a new sheet of the found vins, this will do it. You can run it from the created menu.

```
function onOpen() {
 SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu(
    'Vins', [ 
      { name: 'Find Vins', functionName: 'findVins' },
      ]);  
}
function findVins() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var s=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")//get sheet with vin list
  var lr = s.getLastRow()
    s.getRange(2, 1, lr-1, 1).clearFormat()//clear background color 
  var vinToSearch=s.getRange(2, 1, lr-1, 4).getValues()//get vin list values
  var s1=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2")//get sheet with vins to find
  var lr1=s1.getLastRow()
  var vinToFind=s1.getRange(2, 1, lr1-1, 1).getValues()//get vins to find
  var found=[]
  for(var i=0;i<vinToFind.length;i++){
     for(var j=0;j<vinToSearch.length;j++){
      if(vinToFind[i][0]== vinToSearch[j][0]){//if numbers match
        found.push([vinToSearch[j][0],vinToSearch[j][1],vinToSearch[j]
[2],vinToSearch[j][3]])
       }}}
  var s2=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet3")
  var lr2 = s2.getLastRow()
  var lc2 =s2.getLastColumn()
  s2.getRange(2, 1, lr2, lc2).clearContent()
  s2.getRange(2, 1, found.length, found[0].length).setValues(found)
}
```

Here is a shared spreadsheet you can copy and try.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bC8SP6vVY0cMoZVg3lpo2ZtI2ch4FJ7kztlNHAVBWF8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: I noticed some people commenting were saying they were not too sure what my actual question was so I thought this might help: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1xSdN42zpL-9SjGtCzvAArfeaccOXaJkGoAOGLYlcDJ4/pubhtml

Comment: Hi Ed, first off thanks so much! Second, Would this be grabbing the list of VINs from sheet 1 or 2 and then applying that to the other list of thousands of VINs? Is that why it says getsheetbyname("sheet1")? In which case, would I need to replace "sheet1" with the name of the file that is being used to collect the VINs from? Also, for "vinToSearch=s.getRange(2, 1, lr-1, 1).getValues()//get vin list values", this does not mean I put the list of vins where (2, 1 lr-1, 1) is, correct? Rather that is the formula used to calculate the correct VIN list values?

Comment: Yes, you need to change the sheet names to what you want. Sheet1 is the big vin list. Sheet2 is what you want to find. Now, Sheet3 is the returned matching list. Let me know if you have any more questions.